# How do I style my grid View like this?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My gridView code is as follows :

```
<asp:GridView ID = "GridView2" runat = "server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#262e33"
    DataSourceID = "sourceProducts" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
    CssClass=" table table-hover Grid" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" PageSize="25" Height="800px" Width="1200px" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#153447" >
    <RowStyle Height="5px" />
     <Columns> 
       <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText = "RunID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx?runId={0}" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField = "prodDate" HeaderText = "Date"  DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" ItemStyle-Width="10%"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField = "buildNumber" HeaderText = "Build Number" ItemStyle-Width="10%"/>                  
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="PercentAnalysed" DataTextField="PercentAnalysed" HeaderText="Percent Analysed" ItemStyle-Width="10%"/>            
     </Columns>
     <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I want to acheive the following :

a)I have used bootstrap's "table-hover" css class in the gridView but it works only for alternate rows.I want it to work for all rows.

b)I want all the borders to disappear.I tried border:none;
    border-collapse:collapse; but it doesn't work.
I also tried changing the border colour to that of the background.That works but on hovering the border can be seen as the colour will change.

c) Control the number of entries in a page using a dropdown.To be precise the page size value should be controlled by the value of dropdown.
I tried:PageSize="<% Convert.ToString("#DropDownList1.SelectedValue") %>" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of depending on the GridView properties, you'll be better off using CSS to do your styling.

Comment: @Babak Naffas : But how do I control properties like row width,hover for all rows etc. using css?

Comment: Like @BabakNaffas said, If you want more control on your styling, you will need to add CSS. Gridview is an easy control to use but it has limitation when it comes to customizing. Learn some basic table styling with CSS. Another option is to look into the other controls such as repeater or listview.