# Styling header text in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Q1.  I have a hyperlink field in a grid view as below :

```
<asp:HyperLinkField  Text="Analyze" />
```

I want it to be underlined at all times and not only when I hover. How do I do this ?

Q2. I want the header texts of the gridView to be center alligned.

I tried:   `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"` but it doesn't work.

I also tried making a css class with :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header-center{
        text-align:center;}
</style>
```

but this also doesn't work.

I am basically trying to center the header text,nothing fancy,but it is not happening.

Comment: did you try modify the position in the grid column properties?

Comment: What do you mean by "position" ? Sorry,I didn't get you.

Comment: you can get the column properties using Edit Columns options in gridview.in that you can set the horizontal alignment of that control in item style.

Comment: It is available for all fields but not for header text.

Comment: can you please put an image of your gridview as you expected?

Comment: I am trying to do that but it says you need 10 reputation to post images :(

Comment: "I want it to be underlined at all times and not only when I hover. How do I do this ?" for this you have to add a CssClass to itemstyle property like this  .link {text-decoration: underline;}.

Comment: you want this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Comment: I tried doing this :Edit Columns and then changed header style.It still doesn't work :( I wish I could somehow show you through pictures or something :/

Comment: yeh, that will be better. you see that MSDN link? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx

Comment: Yeah,i saw that and did what they are showing in Fig 11 but not working

Comment: @frebin francis : I am doing this college project with a friend.He can post pictures in stack overflow.He has 15 reputation. If you can help us with this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403244/how-do-i-style-my-grid-view-like-this?rq=1

Comment: Anyways,thanks for all your effort :) :)

Comment: you got the answer ?

Comment: No,I didn't. But thank you for trying :) :) I have posted another link in comments..you can post if you know the answer there :)

Comment: sure i will get the answer and will post it.

Comment: you want only answers for two questions as you specified in the question?

Comment: No,the second one only.The first one is not required.

Comment: The link is posted in the comments

Comment: see my posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace your code in BodyContent with the below.
Note: you can add your own colors to the grid

[image: See the image below]

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <style type="text/css">
        #MainContent_GridView2 tbody tr th {
            text-align: center;
            background: #808080;
            height: 40px;
        }

        #MainContent_GridView2 tbody tr {
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #CCC;
        }

            #MainContent_GridView2 tbody tr:hover {
                background-color: #808080;
            }

            #MainContent_GridView2 tbody tr td {
                text-align: center;
                height: 30px;
            }

        .linkfield {
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"
        runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True"
        PageSize="25"
        Height="800px"
        Width="1200px"
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText="RunID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx?runId={0}" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemStyle Width="10%" CssClass="linkfield"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:HyperLinkField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="prodDate" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemStyle Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="buildNumber" HeaderText="Build Number" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemStyle Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="PercentAnalysed" DataTextField="PercentAnalysed" HeaderText="Percent Analysed" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemStyle Width="10%"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:HyperLinkField>
        </Columns>
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you want any further changes please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403244/how-do-i-style-my-grid-view-like-this?rq=1 : Is it for this ?

Comment: This code is giving some content page error.Have you used a master page?

Comment: no actually it's mainly focus on your needs, align header text on center.

Comment: yes, the code which i used here is from the link that you sent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403244/how-do-i-style-my-grid-view-like-this?rq=1 Do appropriate changes

Comment: Can you address the questions on that link also please ?

Comment: of course i will try it and come back with answers.

Comment: Frebin francis - I figured out the entire issue is happening because I am using bootstrap classes.That is why even this code has no effect on the alignment of header text.I think bootstrap overrides other styling.

Comment: I think I should remove bootstrap but then the hovering effect on rows won't come

Comment: yes that might be the reason for that issue.we can create the hover effect without bootstrap very easily.

Comment: can we talk on gmail or something only if it is okay with you ? I can send pictures and it will be easier

Comment: you can reach me at frebinfrancis7@gmail.com